# Problem in flash mp3 audio player

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I did an audio player using as3 and its working fine if run as using standalone player...

If I embed in HTML.. I am not hearing any sound..

Can u guess where do I made mistake?

Comment: To make an educated guess requires an educated question.

Comment: from the data you provided my guess would be: you are using Windows7, and in the sound mixer, you setted your browser volume to 0.

Comment: Might be a networking sandbox problem

Comment: @ Jevgenij Dmitrijev : No.. windows xp only.

Comment: I didn't instantiate Number class, for which I have used for soundChannel to get the current position. That is the problem.

But I didn't know!!! why its running perfectly in standalone flash player.

 May be flash player version is differnce... think so..

Thanks to all..

Answer (score 1):

Here are some common newbie mistakes that could cause your problems:

- Flash tries to load "somesong.mp3" while the file actually is named "somesong.MP3". Windows doesn't know capitals in filenames, linux does.
- Cross server loading fails since the crossdomains.xml file is missing
- paths inside flash are relative to the EXE/HTML file. If you have your SWF in a subfolder different from your HTML file, this could lead to the mp3 file not being found.

Obviously those are wild guesses. As long as you don't describe how your system looks and what you actually do and maybe post some code there's no way to actually tell you where your issues come from.

Comment: I didn't instantiate Number class, for which I have used for soundChannel to get the current position. That is the problem.

But I didn't know!!! why its running perfectly in standalone flash player.

 May be flash player version is differnce... think so..